# Searching the ServiceController array using Array.Findall?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, service, servicecontroller

I'm rusty at the moment coding in .NET again, and am trying to avoid doing a `For Each` loop, playing with `Array.Findall`.

I want to grab an array of all services installed on the machine, and then pass a string to search it's Friendly Display Name for any matches; if found, return the matches along with their actual service name.

i.e. Pass the string "Calibre", which will search all services for any that have "Calibre" in their Display Name. I'm doing this as a sort of "fuzzy search" in case the actual service name isn't known, and in case there happens to be more than one that match the passed string, a bunch of services won't be started/stopped.

I have:

```
Dim strServiceName = "Calibre"  
Dim scServices() As ServiceController = ServiceController.GetServices()  
Dim value2() As String = Array.FindAll(scServices, Function(x) x.DisplayName.ToLower().Contains(strServiceName))
```

But get the error:

> Value of type '1-dimensional array of
>   System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController' cannot be converted to
>   '1-dimensional array of String' because
>   'System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController' is not derived from
>   'String'."

I know I'm probably missing something real simple, but it's eluding me at the moment, lol.

Comment: Just a question, why no  For Each loop?

Comment: @Creator: A few different reasons really; one is I've been mostly coding in PHP lately and have gotten used to the nice set of Array functions, where you don't have to use cycles looping through individual items (plus their convenience). It's also cleaner as far as code clarity goes, at least imho, and also, I'm wanting to do some profiling tests between a standard loop and the .Find/.FindAll functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The genetic type of `Array.FindAll<T>` returned is the same as the genetic type of array, which is ServiceController here.

If you want to get all the services' name which contains the specific name in their `DisplayName`, you should select the `DisplayName` out from the `ServiceController` like this:

```
Dim value2() As String = Array.FindAll(scServices, Function(x) x.DisplayName.ToLower().Contains(strServiceName))
                              .Select(Function(x) x.DisplayName).ToArray()
```